# How to query data in fusion tables

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have two datasets on fusion tables. One is a points layer (libraries) and the other is a polygon layer (land parcels). How do I design a query using Google Maps/fusion table to figure out this question: how many land parcels are within 1km (for example) of the library?

Also, I've seen some of the like this one where the search distance is pre-defined. Is it possible to design a query that doesn't have predefined search distances? I would prefer to have the distance undefined.

I understand that this task will require the use of javascript (I'm still a beginner), so help in that area would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API 3. (tag removed)

Comment: You refer to some examples but don't provide any links, code or information about what you have tried, or for that matter what language you are working in. Can you edit your question to provide more details?